# Gradual deprecation of importprivkey call?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development, wallet.dat, private-key-import

I'm running bitcoin core 26.0 on debian 12.

```
$ /usr/local/bin/bitcoin-26.0/bin/bitcoin-cli importprivkey "5-rest-of-priv-key"
error code: -4
error message:
Only legacy wallets are supported by this command
```

Okay so I can have bitcoin core 26.0 run with an old wallet.dat file, and the priv-key import will then work fine, so that's nice. But, this works **only** with **old** wallet.dat files.

Are there any plans, or is there a widely shared disposition among developers, to stop future releases of bitcoin core from being able to import priv-keys to *old* wallet.dat files -- as is already the case with *newly created* wallet.dat files -- and thus to deprecate the "importprivkey" call completely?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, `importprivkey` will stop being supported entirely whenever support for legacy wallets is removed, [probably](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/20160) in version 28.0. Old wallets will of course be covertible to the new format.

However, it is perfectly possible to import things into new wallets that involve private keys, using the `importdescriptors` RPC, which has different arguments and different semantics, but almost certainly covers your use case. See the documentation for `importprivkey`, which mentions:

> Note: This command is only compatible with legacy wallets. Use "importdescriptors" with "combo(X)" for descriptor wallets.

The reason for not supporting `importprivkey` in legacy wallets is that its behavior is hard to reason about, and intentionally not supported anymore for descriptor wallets:

- `importprivkey` is effectively a "here is a key, figure out what I want to do with it". It will cause certain (but not all) single-key addresses related to that key to become part of the wallet, but it will also do things like making a multisig script the wallet knew about go from watch-only to fully supported if it now has all its keys.
- With `importdescriptor` (and the philosophy behind descriptor wallets in general), you have to be explicit about what/how you want to use the key.